# Who may initialize "refresher"?

Tags: sip

I read SIP protocol and one question is unclear for me.
I see that "refresher" can be installed in OK response for INVITE message.
And INVITE doesn't contain refresher in "session-expired" header.

But what if we send "refresher" value in INVITE message? In other words - UAS can define value of "refresher", or not?

Answer (score 1):

sorry for the delay.

if you take a look at:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4028#page-16
you can see the third columns, the param of the refresher is based on the UAC (the user agent that initiated the INVITE in your case) and what the UAS supports (the user agent that received the INVITE in your case).

So, to answer your question:

> But what if we send "refresher" value in INVITE message? In other
> words - UAS can define value of "refresher", or not?

The answer is no, this is the case of the 5th and 6th row in the table 2.

Answer (score 0):

The UAC MAY include the refresher parameter with value 'uac' if it
   wants to perform the refreshes.